# submitEl.triggerEventHandler is not a function in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test cases in Angular5 Jasmine. I am trying to submit a form. I am writing unit test cases for submitting the form. Below is my form.

```
<form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="scopesEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && isScopeValid() ? saveScope() : showErrorAlert('Please enter mandatory fields')">
     <input autofocus type="text" id="scopename" name="scopename" placeholder="Enter scope name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="scopeEdit.scopevalue" #scopename="ngModel" required />
     <button type="button" (click)="editorModal.hide()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Below is my spec.ts file.

```
describe('ScopeEditorComponent', () => {

    let component: ScopeEditorComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ScopeEditorComponent>;
    let submitEl: DebugElement;
    let scopeValue: DebugElement;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                 RouterTestingModule,
                 ],
            declarations: [
                ScopeEditorComponent,
                SearchBoxComponent,
                GroupByPipe,
            ]
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ScopeEditorComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        service = new PermissionEndpointMock();
        fixture.detectChanges();


        submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
        scopeValue = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#scopename'));
  }));

 it('should create the scope component', async(() => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    }));
     it('add scope', () => {
        let scope: Scope;
        scopeValue.nativeElement.value = "test@example.com";

        // Subscribe to the Observable and store the user in a local variable.
        component.addscopeEventEmitter.subscribe((value) => scope = value);
        // This sync emits the event and the subscribe callback gets executed above
        submitEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

        // Now we can check to make sure the emitted value is correct
        expect(scope.scopeid).toBe("123456");
    });
```

Below code throws error submitEl.triggerEventHandler is not a function. Can someone help me to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

try to use

```
submitEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
```

then

```
submitEl.click();
```

Answer (score 3):

`triggerEventHandler` is not defined on the `nativeElement`; inside `describe`, change

```
submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
```

to,

```
submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
```

Comment: That was it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way:

```
submitEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
submitEl.click();
```

But, unfortunately it just emits a click event, but doesn't start the click handler from the component.
The only way I've found, is just to call the handler explicitly:

```
component.editorModal.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Three important facts about the triggerEventHandler() method:

1. It will invoke the event handler only if it was declared on the native element by using Angular event bindings, the @HostListener() or @Output decorators (and the less used Renderer.listen()).
2. It will not trigger change detection automatically; we need to call it ourselves.
3. Different from what developers think or do, there is no need to use fakeAsync — The handler will be executed synchronously.